# Use TQuery.Locate() function to find other then first matching

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2006, bde

Locate moves the cursor to the first row matching a specified set of search criteria. 
Let's say that `q` is `TQuery` component, which is connected to the database with two columns `TAG` and `TAGTEXT`. With next code I am getting letter `a`. And I would like to use `Locate()` function to get letter `d`.

```
 If q.Locate('TAG','1',[loPartialKey]) Then
  begin
    tag60 := q.FieldByName('TAGTEXT');
  end
```

For example if I got table like this:

```
TAG | TAGTEXT
+---+--------+
| 1 | a      |
+---+--------+
| 2 | b      |
+---+--------+
| 3 | c      |
+---+--------+
| 1 | d      |
+---+--------+
| 4 | e      |
+---+--------+
| 1 | f      |
+---+--------+
```

is it possible to locate the second time number one occurred in table?

**EDIT**

My job is to find the occurrence of `TAG` with value `1` (which occurrence I need depends on the parameter I get), I need to iterate through table and get the values from all the TAGTEXT fields till I find that value in TAG field is again number 1. Number 1 in this case represents the start of new segment, and all between the two number 1s belongs to one segment. *It doesn't have to be same number of rows in each segment.* Also I am not allowed to do any changes on table.

What I thought I could do is to create a counter variable that is going to be increased by one every time it comes to `TAG` with value `1` in it. When the counter equals to the parameter that represents the occurrence I know that I am in the right segment and I am going to iterate through that segment and get the values I need. 
But this might be slow solution, and I wanted to know if there was any faster.

Comment: why not doing that directly from an SQL query?

Comment: There are multiple options. I cannot tell you the appropriate way
1. Change your sql query e.g. use skip and select first 
2. Go to the first item in your query and iterate until you hit TAG with your value a second time

Those options could work - it depends on your scenario though

Comment: Maybe use a [`Filter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter)?

Comment: @RBA because it depends which one I need on the parameter I am getting from other part of the code. The table is much bigger and for example if I get parameter = 55, I would need to locate the 55th time number 1 occurred, move the cursor to that row and get the value from `TAGTEXT` (it's not really number one, it's simplified and the table also got more columns).

Comment: Actually what I really need to do is when I find the 55th occurrence (from the my comment above), I need to iterate through table and get the values from all the `TAGTEXT` fields till I find that value in `TAG` field is again number 1. 
Number 1 in this case represents the start of new segment, and all between the two number 1s belongs to one segment.

Comment: 2 qs:  a) What database backend are you using?  TQuery is for the BDE, which has been obsolete for two decades.   b) does your table include a column which identifies entries whiich belong to the same block of rows, e.g. a SegmentID?  If not, you should add one.

Comment: @nikname  if you need to find the 55th occurrence, that should be part of your question.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046023/8041231).

Comment: @MartynA I am using SQL Server and I don't have any 'SegmentID' as I am not creator of this table. The company I am working for have made them and my job is to do as written in question.

Comment: @JohnEasley 55th occurrence was an example (as I have written). It could be 1st, 5th, 101th or any other occurrence and it is based on the parameter I get from other part of the code.

Comment: You never answer which dataset component you use. and which provder? And why cant you use a filter?

Comment: @Victoria I'm *almost* sure it is a duplicate.

Comment: @kobik You are giving minuses to me but you never read the whole question. If you look carefully I have written that I am using `TQuery` component which is part of `BDE` dataset. And the other question that you are saying that is same as mine is about `ADO` dataset.

Comment: I updated your answer and reverted my downvote. I cant see other better option other than to iterate the dataset if you use  bde and. cant modify your table. Goog luck.

Comment: @kobik That's exactly the answer I needed! If there is no better way than this then I'd better get to work.

Comment: @nikname, if you were using FireDAC, I would know a more efiicient way, but it's not your case.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks anyway. I have already done this as I have explained up there.
But I remembered of another way. I could create stored procedure to do what I need and later execute it in Delphi. If I find enough time for this way, I am going to do it and post it here later.

Comment: I bet there's no need for SP here. A single SQL command can do that, I think (parametrized, executed from your Delphi client app.). I'm not sure if I got your requirement well though (so far I would simply say `SELECT TagText FROM MyTable WHERE Tag = :Tag ORDER BY TagText`).

Comment: @Victoria Ordering by `tagtext` won't help as in that column could be any string, there isn't any rule for the values in that column. And also the query you have written would only return `tagtext` for 1st occurrence of the tag written in where clause, and that doesn't work for me as I need the occurrence that equals to the number given in parameter that I get from other part of the code.

Comment: _" the query you have written would only return tagtext for 1st occurrence of the tag written in where clause"_ That's not correct. But it doesn't matter :)

Comment: does your sql server supports row_number()?

Comment: @Atys Yes it does. And now I see what I could do with it. I could call `row_number()` two times, first time to find the occurrence and second time to go through whole segment (till I find another occurrence of `TAG = 1`). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit wary of using `Locate` for a purpose like this, because some
`TDataSet` descendants' implementation of `Locate` (or the underlying db-access layer) construct a temporary index on the dataset. which can be discarded immediately afterwards, so repeatedly calling `Locate` to iterate the rows of a given segment may be a lot more inefficient than one might expect it to be.

Also, `TClientDataSet` constructs, uses and then discards an expression parser for each invocation of `Locate` (in its internal call to `LocateRecord`), which is a lot of overhead for repeated calls, especial when they are entirely avoidable.

In any case, the best way to do this is to ensure that your table records which segment a given row belongs to, adding a column like the `SegmentID` below if your table does not already have one:

```
TAG | TAGTEXT|SegmentID
+---+--------+---------+
| 1 | a      |     1
| 2 | b      |     1
| 3 | c      |     1
| 1 | d      |     2
+---+--------+---------+  // btw, what happened to the 2 missing rows after this one?
| 4 | e      |     2
| 1 | f      |     3
+---+--------+---------+
```

Then, you could use code like this to iterate the rows of a segment:

```
procedure IterateSegment(Query : TSomeTypeOfQueryComponent; SegmentID : Integer);
var
  Sql; String;
begin
  Sql := Format('select * from mytable where SegmentID = %d order by Tag', [SegmentID]);
  if Query.Active then
    Query.Close;
  Query.Sql.Text := Sql;

  Query.Open;

  Query.DisableControls;
  try
    while not Query.Eof do begin
      //  process row here
      Query.Next;
    end;
  finally
    Query.EnableControls;
  end;

end;
```

Once you have the `SegmentID` column in the table, if you don't want to open a new query to iterate a block, you can set up a local index (by `SegmentID` then `Tag`), assuming your dataset type supports it, set a filter on the dataset to restrict it to a given `SegmentID` and then iterate over it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem.
First, I am not allowed to add column `SegmentID`. Second, there are no missing rows, I have simplified this table, but in real table values in column `TAG` are combination of numbers and letters. For example number 1 here is `:21R` in real table. And I am not guaranteed how many rows are between two occurrences of that tag (it may differ).

Comment: @nikname:  Well, even so, what you need to do is straightforward.  I'm busy this morning but will try to post an update about it later on.

Comment: Thanks. Have a look on my question again, I have edited it with my suggestion of solution. See if that one is fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have much options to do this.

If your component don´t provide a locateNext you can make your on function locateNext, comparing the value and make next until find.

You can also bring the sql with order by then use locate for de the first value and test if the next value match the comparision.

If you use a clientDataset you can filter into the component filter propertie, or set IndexFieldNames to order values instead the "order by" of sql in the prior suggestion.

You can filter it on the SQL Where clausule too.

Comment: Check my comments under my question please and help me if you can. Thank you!

Comment: @nikname You want all occurrences between the 55th TAG 1 and 56th TAG 1?

Comment: it's not always 55th occurrence, it depends on the parameter I get so it could be any other occurrence.